# Хранение коллекции в БД

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Господа, просветите пожалуйста. Можно ли в БД (MSSQL) хранить коллекцию типа `List<MyClass>`. Получается у меня такая история, есть таблица бд, в которой столбики Name, Type, Orders. В последнем должна быть коллекция со всеми заказами для каждого конкретного Name. Можно ли как-то передать эту коллекцию в БД, если да, то как это можно сделать. Спасибо

Comment: Можно хранить виде XML поля, но зачем настолько разрушать релационность данных?

Comment: Почему бы не сделать под MyClass отдельную таблицу и замапить ее на основную?

Comment: Да, я вот просто прочитал, что так вообще возможно, вот меня и заинтересовало как такое сделать. Не могу понять при конструировании таблицы в БД какой формат выбирать для объектов типа массива ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Обычно это делается через связанную таблицу.

Если речь идет о Entity Framework - то минимальный код очень простой: достаточно добавить саму коллекцию к родительской записи и задать первичный ключ для дочерней записи.

Основная сложность - в удалении дочерних записей. Их нельзя просто удалять из коллекции - их надо удалить из контекста.

Ну а дальше надо читать по EF - чем плоха отложенная загрузка, как загружать дочерние записи вместе с родительской и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Так делать не стоит. Правильно будет для `MyClass` создать отдельную таблицу. То есть в вашем случае таблицу `Orders`, для каждой строки которой будет храниться ссылка на строку в первой таблице. И сохранять отдельно записи в первую таблицу и в таблицу `Orders`.
Если вы используете Entity Framework: Code First, тогда вообще не стоит беспокоиться - EF сам сгенерирует вторую таблицу и ссылки на первую.

Answer (score 2):

а может лучше сделать иначе? например как то так

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    piblic string Name {get;set;}
    public int TypeId {get;set;}///ссылка на справочник
    public int OrderId {get;set;}

    public virtual Type Types {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}

public class Type
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string TypeName {get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Это хороший вариант, но какой тогда тип столбца должен быть у БД  в entity чтобы туда забрасывать такой тип ?

Comment: @polyakov_s не совсем понял вопрос, попробую ответить как понял в  приведенном мной примере будет 3 таблицы. Type это справочник. в table1 хранится ключ для связи с заказами(Order) связь между этими таблицами 1 ко многим т.е. 1 записи в table соответствует несколько записей в order.если Вы имели ввиду не это то перефразируйте вопрос

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Я имел в виду, что когда я конструирую саму таблицу в VS, то там указывается ИМЯ столбика ТИП данных , которые будут там храниться и пр.. Я вот не понял какой там ТИП выбирать при создании таблицы, если я в этом типе буду хранить коллекцию, или другие объекты.